# How can I send a boolean body to HttpClient.PutAsync or HttpClient.PostAsync?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I am trying to invoke a `PUT` service that accepts a single boolean value as a body. The service works when I test it from Javascript or Swagger, but it rejects my request from .NET.

This works (Javascript):

```js
fetch(URL, {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `bearer ${TOKEN}`
    },
    method: 'PUT',
    body: true,
});
```

This does not work (.NET):

```cs
private static async Task<string> RunTest(bool b)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {TOKEN}");
        var content = new StringContent(b.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        HttpResponseMessage result = await client.PutAsync(URL, content);
        return result.ToString();
    }
}
```

The server is returning a `400` for my .NET request. But as I said, it works when I test using `fetch` or other ways. So I assume I am doing something wrong in .NET.

How can I pass a boolean body to `HttpClient.PutAsync`?

Comment: try actually serializing the boolean to JSON instead of just calling `ToString`

Comment: Yep I replaced `b.ToString()` with `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(b)` ([Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)) and it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Nkosi suggested in the comments, I needed to serialize the boolean to JSON instead of just calling `ToString`.

The problem appears to be that `ToString` produces upper-case values of `True` or `False`, instead of the expected lower-case values of `true` or `false`.

So I added a reference to [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) and changed the code to this:

```cs
private static async Task<string> RunTest(bool b)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {TOKEN}");
        var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(b), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        HttpResponseMessage result = await client.PutAsync(URL, content);
        return result.ToString();
    }
}
```

This works.